# How to create a startup script in Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, boot, synergy

I'm new to this so forgive me for asking such a simple question.

I'm trying to run something from the command line everytime I start (or log in to) Snow Leopard. I'm actually trying to imitate this [Synergy+ startup script for Leopard](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/wiki/TipsAndTricks). Problem is the code on that page for Leopard didn't work for me under Snow Leopard. I can get it to work by opening terminal and typing:

```
synergys
```

That starts Synergy+ as a server. So it's as simple as that. Now how do I run this command every time I start my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple menu->System Preferences...->Accounts->Your Account->Login Items

Click '+' icon at the bottom to add "*synergys*".

**OR**

Use terminal and edit or create the /etc/rc file (which is what the GUI based instructions above do.)

You should be able to just place the path to synergys and it, save, and should execute on next startup.

#### UPDATE

based on comment

> defaults write com.apple.finder
>   AppleShowAllFiles TRUE/FALSE
>
> killall Finder *(restarts finder after previous command is executed)*

Comment: synergys is located in /usr/bin so I can't navigate to it from the finder.

Comment: Command Shift G is much easier to navigate to /usr/bin/

Answer (score 1):

From [Synergy Documentation: Autostart](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/autostart.html)

> Mac OS X
>
> [By Tor Slettnes]
>
> There are three different ways to automatically start Synergy (client or server) on Mac OS X:
>
> The first method involves creating a StartupItem at the system level, which is executed when the machine starts up or shuts down. This script will run in the background, and relaunch synergy as needed.
>   Pros:
>   Synergy is persistent, so this allows for a multi-user setup and interactive logins.
>   Cons:
>   The synergy process does not have access to the clipboard of the logged-in user.
>
> The second method will launch Synergy from the LoginWindow application, once a particular user has logged in.
>   Pros:
>   The synergy process inherits the $SECURITYSESSIONID environment variable, and therefore copy/paste works.
>   Cons:
>   Once the user logs out, synergy dies, and no remote control is possible.
>
> The third method is to launch a startup script from the "Startup Items" tab under System Preferences -> Accounts.
>   Pros:
>   Does not require root (Administrator) access
>   Cons:
>   Once the user logs out, synergy dies, and no remote control is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Login Hook :

Use the first method of the [Apple Support Page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420).

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.loginwindow LoginHook /path/to/script
```

Do not forget the `sudo` otherwise it won't work.